Sending API requests from Kibana
I currently have a Kibana dashboard for monitoring my services. I would like to have a sort of button/widget on the dashboard that, if clicked, send a POST request to a third-party API. Is that possible with Kibana?
I know about webhook connectors, but they seem only related to trigger an action if some alert is reached, is that right? I would like to have the trigger independent from the alerting
